# Lebesgue measure nullsets

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question concerning nullsets of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^d$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
I think the set
 $$\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0\}$$
is a nullset of the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Any advice how prove this? I have my difficulties.

Regards,
Analyst77

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n = 0\}$ is a null set?

Answer (score 2):

Another proof would use Fubini's theorem.  Since
$$
E:=\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0\right\}
$$
is a Lebesgue measurable set (it is a closed set), and for each $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ the set
$$
\left\{t \in \mathbb R : (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},t) \in E\right\}
$$
has $1$ dimensional measure zero (it is a single point), we conclude that $E$ itself has $n$ dimensional measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1.This is a hyperlane in $\mathbb R^n$. For each $\varepsilon >0$ can you cover it with cubes with total volume less than $\varepsilon$?

2.As we can split a straight line in compact line segments, split the hyperplance in compact subsets. Prove that each comact subset is a null set. Then the hyperplance is the countable union of these sets, therefore a null set.

Comment: It's probably easier to think of balls rather than cubes.

Comment: The dimensions of each cube can be $1\times 1\times 1\dots\times 1\times \phi(\varepsilon)$ so you can calculate the volumes easier.